# Merge 2 different actionbars

Tags: java, android

Trying to Add actions to the top action bar for one specific fragment but it seems to have created 2 bars which isn't what I want. There are no actions on the main activity or any other fragments.

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_protein, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this::onOptionsItemSelected);
    return v;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

    }
    return true;
}
```

**XML**

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here's an example to show what I mean
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post your app theme. If you are using `DarkActionBar` then use `NoActionBar` theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a theme with ActionBar, it has it. To avoid this you can use one of NoActionBar themes.

style/themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.StackOverflow" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        (...)
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.StackOverflow">
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, Unrelated question do you know if there's a way to have actions appear only on a specific page or will it be a case of: if on AddFragment then show specific actions

Comment: @TavianT Place toolbars only for Fragments which need in their respective layouts (ex. R.layout.fragment_add_protein).